# When I highlight a text and and click "search in google", the selection messes up

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, search, highlighting

So, imagine that I'm reading a page and there I find some random text, like "hungarian man escapes jungle", and I try to select that to google search it.

The thing is, I have to select it, with my left mouse button, and then I have to UNCLICK my left mouse button, and only then I can click my right mouse button to open up the window that says "serach in google".

That's a lot of trouble, before I used to be able to do it all in one go, I could select the text, keep presing the left mouse button, click my right mouse button, hover to "search in google", and unclick the left mouse button and that would search the text in google.

If I try to do that now, either it will unselect everything that I have selected, or it will only select random pieces, such as "ngle", or "pes jungle". This is kinda annoying, I know that it's petty haha, but I used to looove doing this little shortcut...

Comment: Well, you should be able to `left click` -> `right click` -> `drag to highlight` -> `release right` -> `Search in google`

Comment: The question needs more specifics about OS, what 'unclick' means (release button? click again?) and any mouse adjustments made; OP has previous question about mouse settings/driver. As it stands, I can't replicate OP's behaviour in Chromium (searches normally), whereas EBGreen's comment (answer!) doesn't.

Comment: Hey, thanks EBGreen, that does work. I'll use that in the meanwhile! :D bertieb, my OS is windows 10. By unclick, I mean release button. I have not made any mouse adjustments! What do you mean, you can't replicate my behaviour? You also can't do what I'm trying to do? What I mean is that when I select something, and then I click on the right mouse button (without releasing the left button, that you need to click to highlight the text) to open the little window that says "copy", "print", "inspect", etc, my selection goes out of the window, and I'm left with just a regular right click window.

Comment: EBGREEN you have hit gold on your reply, I will definitely use this tip further. Tho I think that I recall I didn't need to do that before, maybe my memory is flawed tho. If more users report that they also cannot do it, maybe it's indeed the normal behaviour as tutizeri says?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to see if you have `ClickLock` ON?

Open `Control Panel` go to  `Mouse` and see if it's ticked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey man, good question but I don't have that on. Thanks, tho.

Answer (score -2):

That's the normal behavior in Windows and Linux, Firefox and Chrome. If you are using a different OS /Browser, you should explain it.

Comment: Thanks man, I don't recall changing browser tho, but it's good to know that I'm not the only 1.